# Skia Failed to create Image decoder with message 'unimplemented'

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a CutImagesPage where users in the App should be allowed to crop thweir images before uploading, there i am Using Skiasharp to crop the Images. After Cropping the Image gets Saved as a byte[] as you can see in my code. The AppManager, where the byte[[] gets saved, notifies the CreateAccount Page which gets the byte[] from the Manager and sets its own ProfileImage Property. In the View i am usign the ByteArrayToImageConverter to displayx the page. The Problem is now that i get following error during the Process of showing the image. I looked it up on Google but all SOlutions where with an Image beeing loaded from the Ressources which is not the case here.

```
    [skia] --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'
    [skia] --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'
    [System] A resource failed to call close. 
    [System] A resource failed to call close.
```

The Image Cropping Page:

```
    public SKBitmap ProfileImage { get; set; }

public async void SetImages()
    {
        try
        {
            if (isProfileImage)
            {
                foreach (CutImages cutImage in ImageObjects)
                {
                    ProfileImage = cutImage.CroppedImage.Resize(new SKImageInfo(360, 360), SKFilterQuality.High);
                }
                AppManager.ProfileImage = this.ProfileImage.Bytes;

                await NavigationService.GoBackAsync();
                ImageObjects.Clear();
                return;
            }
            foreach (CutImages cutImage in ImageObjects)
            {
                PostImages.Add(cutImage.CroppedImage.Resize(new SKImageInfo(1080,1080),SKFilterQuality.High));
            }
            NavigationService.InsertNavigateBefore<CreatePostViewModel>();
            ImageObjects.Clear();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
```

The Method Setting the Image:

```
public override void AppManager_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.AppManager_PropertyChanged(sender, e);
        if(e.PropertyName == nameof(AppManager.CroppedImage))
        {
            ProfileImage = AppManager.CroppedImage;
        }
    }
```

The View:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <xct:ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter x:Key="ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter"/>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
            <ffimageloading:CachedImage Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                                        Source="{Binding ProfileImage, 
                                        Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter}}" 
                                        HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" >
                
            </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
```

Comment: Do you get an actual exception, or just a console log message?  It’s unclear where specifically in the code it is failing

Comment: I only get the Console log message. And the Image does not get shown in the view.

Comment: Which platform are you testing on?

Comment: Android Emulator on Windows.

Comment: While testing i noticed something itneresting. If i create the byte Array of the Image by creating and SKImage, encode the Image, make a stream out of it and user Stream.ToArray() everything works great. Using SkBitmap.Bytes however does not work at all. Why is this? What is the Problem with SkBitmap.bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/skiasharp.skbitmap.bytes?view=skiasharp-2.88#skiasharp-skbitmap-bytes)

> SKBitmap Bytes **Gets a copy of all the pixel data as a byte array.**

this is the **raw pixel data**, which Xamarin Forms cannot work with.  XF supports encoded image formats like PNG, JPG, etc.  You need to **encode** `SKBitmap` as one of those image formats, and then get the byte data from that encoded image

Comment: Ohh ok i understand i did not think about that the byte arrays look different in different image formats. Makes sense thank you a lot.